# How to send unread messages notifications with Server Sent Events in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, notifications, server-sent-events

I'm new to Spring Boot and web applications. I have to send notifications of unhandled/unread messages from a Spring Boot backend to a web client. I decided to use Server Sent Events since I think I don't need a bidirectional connection (otherwise I'd have thought of WebSockets).

I made a very simple REST controller which finds all unhandled messages in a db and sends them to the client. The problem is that it keeps sending forever all the messages, while I'd like to send a message only when it is added to the db, or when the client first connects to the server.

The behaviour I'd like to achieve is similar to a mail client or a messaging app, in which the user is notifyed not only on new messages but also of previous ones if he/she didn't mark them as read. The notification should happen only once when the client connects, not loop forever.

Here is my code:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class SseEmitterController {

    private MessageDAO messageDAO;

    private ExecutorService nonBlockingService = Executors
            .newCachedThreadPool();

    @Autowired
    public SseEmitterController(MessageDAO messageDAO) {
        this.messageDAO = messageDAO;
    }

    @GetMapping("/incoming_messages")
    public SseEmitter handleSse() {
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
        nonBlockingService.execute(() -> {
            try {
                List<Message> messages = messageDAO.findByHandledFalse();

                for (Message message: messages) {
                    emitter.send(message, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                }

                emitter.complete();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                emitter.completeWithError(ex);
            }
        });
        return emitter;
    }
}
```

I know that the problem is caused by the fact that I query the db inside handleSse method, but I couldn't figure out how to do it outside.
Could you please help me?

**Update October 05, 2021**
I found out how to solve the problem, I didn't update the question because I didn't have the time, but since someone asked me to do so in the comments, I'm gonna explain my solution, hoping it may be helpful.

Here's my code:

The SseEmitterController is responsible for invoking the SseService on frontend's request:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class SseEmitterController {

    private final SseService sseService;

    @Autowired
    SseEmitterController(SseService sseService) {
        this.sseService = sseService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/incoming_messages")
    public ResponseEntity<SseEmitter> handleSse() {

        final SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
        sseService.addEmitter(emitter);
        emitter.onCompletion(() -> sseService.removeEmitter(emitter));
        emitter.onTimeout(() -> sseService.removeEmitter(emitter));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(emitter, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

The SseService is called on a new message arrival (from another part of the application) and sends the notification (actually a server sent event) to the frontend (which previously called the endpoint in the controller above.
The service is called like so: `sseService.sendHelpRequestNotification(helpRequest);`

```
@Service
public class SseService {

    private final List<SseEmitter> emitters = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();


    public void addEmitter(final SseEmitter emitter) {
        emitters.add(emitter);
    }

    public void removeEmitter(final SseEmitter emitter) {
        emitters.remove(emitter);
    }

    public void sendMessagesNotification(Message message) {
        List<SseEmitter> sseEmitterListToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
        emitters.forEach((SseEmitter emitter) -> {
            try {
                emitter.send(message, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                sseEmitterListToRemove.add(emitter);
            }
        });
        emitters.removeAll(sseEmitterListToRemove);
    }
}
```

And finally there is another controller to get all previous unhandled messages (not involving server sent events):

```
@GetMapping(value = "/unhandled_help_requests")
public ResponseEntity<List<HelpRequest>> getUnhandledMessages() {
    List<Message> resultSet = messageDAO.findByHandledFalse(Sort.by("date").and(Sort.by("time")));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(resultSet, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

So, to sum it up: the frontend calls the SseEmitterController to listen for new SSEs. These SSEs are created and sent whenever a new message arrives to the backend, via the SseService. Finally, to get all unhandled (for whatever reason) messages, there is a specific old fashioned controller.

Comment: your problem was solved ?

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. Yes, I solved it. I didn't update or answer to my own question because of lack of time. Anyway, I solved it by using a separate controller for requesting old unhandled messages and using the sse emitter only for sending new messages on their arrival, via a service. It was pretty simple, my mistake was to try to solve this as a single problem while actually they were two different problems.

Comment: can you update the answer there? I am also stuck.

Comment: @SYEDMUSTAFAHUSSAIN Done.